# convert array of numbers to array of words

Tags: java, string, int

I'm trying to convert array of numbers to array of words for example:

`{1,2}` will converted to `{"one","two"}`

so this is the code that I write in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2));

    Integer [] list1Array = list1.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    int numLength2 = list1.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < numLength2; i++){
        System.out.println(list1Array[i]);
     }   
    System.out.println(numLength2);
    String n2 = ""; 
    for(int j = 0; j < numLength2; j++) {
       int element = list1.get(j);
       System.out.println(element);
       switch (element) {
              case '1': {  
                    n2 = n2 + "one";
                    break;
                }
              case '2': { 
                    n2 = n2 + "two";
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    n2 = n2 + "zero";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(n2);
    }
}
```

It works fine except the last print:

```
 System.out.println(n2);
```

The output here is `zerozero` while it should be `onetwo`. What's problem with code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`element` is an `int`, but you're comparing it to a `char` literal. You should use `int` literals instead:

```
switch (element) {

    case 1: {  
        n2 = n2 + "one";

        break;
    }
    case 2: { 
        n2 = n2 + "two";
        break;
    }

    default: {
        n2 = n2 + "zero";
    }
}
```

Comment: @GNDevs If this solved your issue, please do consider selecting it as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: I will but there is a note says that I should wait 3 minutes until I can accept the answer @Mike Bruesch

Comment: @Mureinik sorry but in the question I said that I tried to convert numbers array to words array too and the result now is string so can I make the it array like{"one","two"}?

Answer (score 1):

`case '1'`  , `'1'` is `char` type but `element` is `int`

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you change this line and the program will work:

```
int element = '0' + list1.get(j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have achieved same through these few lines of codes instead of your forloop and switch.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 4));
    String[] numArray = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

    for (Integer num : list1) {
        System.out.print(numArray[num]);
    }
}
```

This prints,

```
onetwofivefour
```

Now as you said you want to create a list like {"one", "two"}, you can do something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 4));
    String[] numArray = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    List<String> wordList = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (Integer num : list1) {
        wordList.add(numArray[num]);
    }
    System.out.println(wordList); // prints [one, two, five, four]
}
```